# Set more then one Flags at once in Paint Object in Android

Tags: android

Well  problem is i want to set two different flag in paint object in android at once

for example

```
Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint.setTextSize(40);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

OR

```
   paint.setFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

And Then

```
     canvas.drawText("Setting Two Flags", 10, 30, paint);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But it is not happening if i set UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG the the Effect of Anti Alias is Removed.
what if i want my text to have Strike out and underline Both Effect.is there any way to set Two flags at once in Paint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OR operator on flags.

```
 paint.setFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```